# how to tell if my beta app is on the play store?

Tags: android

I've pushed a beta version of my app to the play store and am now trying to see it in the play store on my device.  It's not showing up.

How can I tell whether it has been published?

When I go to the play store on my laptop and search for my app, only the production version shows.  If I click on the search result, it goes to the app store page with a warning "you don't have any devices".  That part is fine.  But should the search results also show my beta version?

I've set up a google group of which I'm a member.

I'm assuming that if the play store shows it on my laptop and doesn't show it on my device, then I have some sort of configuration problem - that is what I'm trying to debug in the first place.   However, without knowing if the beta version is published, I'm in the dark.

Any one know how to deal with this situation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about application publication.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to verify that the Beta app is installed on your device is to actually install the app on your device from the Google Play store using the account with which you have opted-in to the Beta Test group.  You can then verify that the **Version Code** of the Apk **is** indeed the Version Code of the BETA Apk that you have uploaded. You might want to print the version code to logcat as your app stats so that you can verify it easily.  You can then also opt-out of the BETA test and reinstall the app through the Play Store and verify that it is **NOT** the Beta Apk by once again looking for the version code.

Comment: Please re-read my question.  My app (neither beta nor production) is showing up on the store when searched from my device.  I was hoping there's a way to verify that the beta version is actually in the store.  Then I would be able to debug why it isn't showing up on the device.

Comment: hmm..  if its not showing up in the Play Store on your device, then it seems like your device is on the unsupported list for your Apk maybe?  Check Developer Console > Apk and verify that API LEVEL of the deployed Apk is equal to or less than the API LEVEL of your device.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what is causing the production version not to show up on my device.  I thought I would use this opportunity to learn how to do beta "pushes".  Again, the production version of the app shows up on the store when viewed from my desktop and the beta version does not.  This has nothing to do with API level.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store now allows open and closed beta testing, although this was not always the case.  If your application is in *open* beta testing, then it should be in the search results, given you've got a version in production.  (I'm lead to believe that if your app is in open beta but you don't have a production version, it will *not* be in the search results).

In order to test to see if your application is available in the search results, you must disassociate yourself with your developer Google account to do your search.  This will remove the association that your Google account has already with the application.  It sounds like you've done that "on your laptop" since it says you say it says you have no devices.  If your computer is logged into Google, you'll need to open a private browsing window or log out of that Google account, then do your search.  If the search returns no results, the application will not be discovered by new users.  But those same new users could still be in the beta by using the beta link that you have the option of distributing.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at this problem.  The beta is now showing up on the store but I don't remember what changed any more.  One thing I've noticed is that you must choose the Android Store app to obtain an alpha or beta download, not a browser.  I've found that the browser will always download the production version.  Go figure.